# How do I integrate Spring Data Elasticsearch (Repository Interface) and template queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Elasticsearch has a concept called [template query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-template-query.html), where we can store a templated query on the Elasticsearch server.

This is an example of how we can store such a query with a single parameter `firstName`:

```
POST _scripts/findByProfileFirstName
{
    "script": {
        "lang": "mustache",
        "source": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "esCandProfile.firstName": "{{firstName}}"
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

This can be invoked using the following example:

```
GET candidates/_search/template
{
    "id": "findByProfileFirstName", 
    "params": {
        "firstName": "Shannon"
    }
}
```

How do I extend **Spring Data Elasticsearch** to achieve the following:

```
public interface CandidateRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Candidate, String> {

    @Query("findByProfileFirstName")
    Page<Candidate> findByCustomQuery(@Param("firstName") String firstName, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**For simplicity, expect the following:**

- The template will be generated/maintained outside of the application lifecycle
- I am willing to go through the trouble of writing this code once to make it work across all template queries

What is the best approach to neatly implement this, preferably within the framework's extension hooks?

Answer (score 0):

For this, we would need to introduce a new annotation like `@TemplateSearch` because `@Query` is used to build a wrapped query that is sent to the _*search* endpoint. Here we need to address the *_search/template* endpoint with different arguments.

The `SearchOperations` interface would need an additional method like `searchByTemplate` which does the call to Elasticsearch, and the Repository logic would need to be adapted to use this new method when a repository method is annotated with the new annotation.

Please create an [issue for this improvement in Jira](https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAES/).